# Creating a flipbook using javascript library 'turn.js' and html

Tags: javascript, html, turn.js

I'm attempting to create a flipbook using the turn.js library. Below is the code that I am using, however it doesn't seem to work. It is currently operating correctly on jsfiddle as shown here [text]http://jsfiddle.net/xd7sh59p/

Where am I going wrong?

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div id="flipbook">
<div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
<div class="hard"></div>
<div> Page 1 </div>
<div> Page 2 </div>
<div> Page 3 </div>
<div> Page 4 </div>
<div class="hard"></div>
<div class="hard"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#flipbook").turn({
width: 400,
height: 300,
autoCenter: true
});

</script>


</body>
</html>   ```
````

Comment: Did you call `jquery` library first ?

Comment: No. I'm a novice at this...how would I do that?

Comment: Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` before your script and before `turn.js` library.

Comment: Can I clarify your suggestion as I have tried adding this code in a number of ways, however it still isn't operating as I would like.... Am I to add the code above twice? If so, would it be once directly above my first <script> tag and another time inside of my original script tag?

Comment: I posted an answer with full example

Comment: I have to thank you for your assistance Ahmed, as I now understand how to correctly load the library, etc. However, when I run the script with the adjustments included what I am seeing in the browser is a grey rectangle that won't 'flip'. This is the same is what is displayed when I press the 'run code snippet' button on this site beneath your code example.

Comment: I have changed the file path for loading turn.js to where turn.js is saved on my laptop (having previously downloaded it), and the code is now fully operational. Thank you very much Ahmed for your assistance and clear guidance with this.

Answer (score 0):

Read code comments

```css
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#flipbook{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

#flipbook .page{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:white;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#flipbook .page-wrapper{
    -webkit-perspective:2000px;
    -moz-perspective:2000px;
    -ms-perspective:2000px;
    -o-perspective:2000px;
    perspective:2000px;
}

#flipbook .hard{
    background:#ccc !important;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#flipbook .odd{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    
}

#flipbook .even{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.95, #fff), color-stop(1, #dadada));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div id="flipbook">
    <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div> Page 1 </div>
    <div> Page 2 </div>
    <div> Page 3 </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
</div>

<!-- Turn.js depends on jQuery library, so load it first -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Then load Turn.js library from CDN [it will not work if you load library directly from turn.js website] -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/turn.js/3/turn.min.js"></script>


<!-- Finally initiate Turn.js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```